# vba excel - Issues with multiple time formats

Tags: vba, excel

[Files here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwLiW8c0PLGGMEdZQ3dMSnB4TVE)

Hello,

I am trying to write code to format a report. The main issue with the report is that some cells store multiple pieces of data in a cell when each row should only have one piece of data in each cell. My solution thus far has been to use the text to columns function for the affected cells, paste all other data transposed, and finally copy and re-transpose the new data over the original report area. This has worked so far, but I am running into an issue with cells that store time. Cells with single times (such as 13:00) are in the custom format hh:mm, which vba converts to a a decimal number. Cells with multiple times (such as 11:009:008:0010:30) are viewed as a string.

The code I am currently using to split the times works for multiple time cells because it searches the string for ":", but vba does not detect the ":" in the custom format cell 13:00 since internally it sees that cells value as something like 0.56412.

I am kind of at a loss as to what to do here. I can't change the format that the report arrive to me in. My thought was that maybe I could find a way to turn the custom format "13:00" into a string "13:00" instead of 0.56412

I have attached the code file and the truncated dummy report I am testing to code on. I would like to thank everyone who responds for their help in advance!

Comment: Maybe use an If Not 'find:' Is Nothing Then.  This will be for the times that are single and double entries.  Else will be for the double entries.

Comment: How many people do you think will download and run your macro-enable files? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to receive more effective help on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change a single time to a string, you can use `format` and identify the value to excel as a string using `'`

example:

```
'immediate window
[a1]="'"&format([a1],"hh:nn")
'or, using a range
range("A1")="'"&format(range("A1"),"hh:nn")
```

you can use `isnumeric` to check if it's a single time. **True** means it's a time, **False** means it's a string of times

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this will work.